# Creating random 2-dimensional array (4x4) FreePascal

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, pascal, freepascal

I have to make random 2-dimensional array (4x4) in FreePascal.
Each element must be between 0 and 100.

For example:

```
12 99 1 85
43 75 5 11
0  100 77 31
64 15 9 74
```

I have tried, but it doesn't work:

```
var
  row:array[1..4] of string = (random(100));
  column:array[1..4] of string = (random(100));
  matrix:array[1..4,1..4] of string;

  x:integer;
  y:integer;

begin

  for x := 1 to 4 do
    for y := 1 to 4 do
      matrix[x,y] := row[x] + column[y];

  for x := 1 to 4 do
    for y := 1 to 4 do
      write(matrix[x,y], ' ');

end.
```

It gives error:

```
Illegal expression
Expected another 3 array elements
Illegal expression
Expected another 3 array elements
```

Can You help me?

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what is the problem you're having. *Doesn't work* is the worst possible description of a problem. Be specific, post the error message you're getting or describe the problem somehow else.

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? did you have some errors, or just output didn't satisfied you? and btw i didnt do pascal for ages, so i might forgot a huge bit, but i dont think structure `row:array[1..4] of string = (random(100));` is valid

Comment: And, please post your real code. This is just a fake code since you wouldn't get this error message. You're having extra `:` symbol behind `var` keyword, which fails compiler on `Syntax error, "identifier" expected but ":" found`.

Comment: @TLama Sorry, it was just a little error which I make when I typed my program here, originally there was not `:`

Comment: No prob. I've upvoted your question after the last correction...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `row` and `column` variables are wrong, since you cannot initialize array by a function call. Those variables are even not necessary as you're having `matrix` already defined. I've changed the `matrix` variable type to be the multidimensional array of integers. This code generates random numbers in the range of 0-100; 0 and 100 including.

```
program Project1;

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  Matrix: array[1..4, 1..4] of Integer;
begin
  Randomize;

  for X := 1 to 4 do
    for Y := 1 to 4 do
      Matrix[X, Y] := Random(101);

  for X := 1 to 4 do
  begin
    for Y := 1 to 4 do
      Write(IntToStr(Matrix[X, Y]), ' ');
    WriteLn;
  end;

  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: +1, It seems as 0 and 100 are valid numbers in the matrix, see posted example.

Comment: @TLama When I want to create 3 matrixes (same layout, different numbers) I must add for cycle? For example `for i := 1 to 3 do`?

Comment: @TLama Because I managed to create 3 matrixes, but there are same numbers.

Comment: You need to enclose also the part where the numbers are generated. Like [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/MPyyS7sg), but if this is your intention, then you don't even need that `Matrix` array variable at all. You could just directly print out the random numbers.

Comment: @TLama Thanks. And 1 problem more, when I have outputed 3 random matrixes, I must output also again matrix, which 16 elements sum are the biggest one. This is the final one, and I'm very thankful if you can help me.

Comment: Please post this as a separate question and try to elaborate more what do you expect as a result (I'm not sure I get what you actually need).

Answer (score 2):

You have declared row,column and matrix as arrays of string.

Change that to arrays of integer.

You need to define your row and column arrays at runtime.

```
var
  row : array[1..4] of Integer;
  column : array[1..4] of Integer;
  matrix : array[1..4,1..4] of Integer;

  x:integer;
  y:integer;

begin
  Randomize; // Init random generator
  for x := 1 to 4 do
  begin
    row[x] := Random(51);
    column[x] := Random(51);
  end;

  for x := 1 to 4 do
    for y := 1 to 4 do
      matrix[x,y] := row[x] + column[y];

  for x := 1 to 4 do
  begin
    for y := 1 to 4 do
    begin
      write(IntToStr(matrix[x,y]), ' ');
    end;
    WriteLn;
  end;
  ReadLn;

end.
```

Comment: Fail! Use `Random(101)` instead... And don't forget to `ReadLn` the result ;-)

Comment: @TLama, yes if he really want 100 as the highest value.

Comment: @LURD Thanks, You are the best, but what are the variables type for row and column?

Comment: Included the variable declarations.

Comment: +1 for the fix, although I don't get the intention of `row` and `column` variables.

Comment: @TLama, I don't know if they will be reused for purpose not shown in the example. If they are temporary placeholders, they can be removed as your example shows.